# How to Parse XML with same tag names?

Tags: xml, parsing, blackberry, java-me, sax

I know how to parse XML with a SAX parser. My XML is like this:

```
-<address_component>
   <long_name>Chambers St</long_name>
   <short_name>Chambers St</short_name>
   <type>route</type>
</address_component>
-<address_component> 
   <long_name>Downtown</long_name>
   <short_name>Downtown</short_name>
   <type>neighborhood</type>
   <type>political</type>
</address_component>
```

My problem: When XML has two tags with same name, like 'type' in this case, my code only gets the value of last tag.  In this case, 'type' gets "political" and it skips "neighborhood".

How do I deal with this?

Comment: The code you use to parse it would be tremendously helpful. ;)

Comment: I want to parse XML from this URL http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=25.665393829345703,-80.29926147460938&sensor=true any suggestion ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your code is not designed to handle multiple `type` elements, so it only saves the last one it encounters.  That is a limitation of your code (which you have not shown).  You need to re-write the code to accept multiple `type` elements, such as by storing every `type` encountered into a `String[]` array instead of a single `String` variable.

Answer (score 0):

XPath maybe (not sure). Check this out (it's for python but it's generic enough): [How to make XPath select multiple table elements with identical id attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888429/how-to-make-xpath-select-multiple-table-elements-with-identical-id-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Considering, that you are, indeed, using a SAX parser, your callbacks (startElement/endElement, etc) should fire for both 'type' elements. Perhaps, if you could post some code, the problem would become more apparent.

Comment: I want to parse XML from this URL http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=25.665393829345703,-80.29926147460938&sensor=true any suggestion ???